# Linux - Gem Error installing PG

Tags: linux, backtrack, gem

I'm getting used to Linux, and currently making a switch to Backtrack 5 to start practicing for school in security. I'm running msfupdate, which installs a bunch of gem files. While installing PG from gem I get this error. How can I go about fixing it?

```
Installing pg (0.15.0) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /opt/metasploit/ruby/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /opt/metasploit/postgresql/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/opt/metasploit/ruby/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
/opt/metasploit/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /opt/metasploit/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:506:in `try_cpp'
    from /opt/metasploit/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:970:in `block in find_header'
    from /opt/metasploit/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
    from /opt/metasploit/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /opt/metasploit/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /opt/metasploit/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
    from /opt/metasploit/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /opt/metasploit/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
    from /opt/metasploit/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
    from /opt/metasploit/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:969:in `find_header'
    from extconf.rb:43:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /opt/metasploit/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.15.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /opt/metasploit/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.15.0/ext/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing pg (0.15.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.15.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error points out, the problem is that configure can't find `libpq-fe.h`. As Backtrack is based on Debian you can get that header installing `libpq-dev` package. So install it before

```
$ sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

and try again.

Comment: That fixed the issue for attempting to install pg separately using gem, but msfupdate still returns the exact same error. Really getting lost here.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `/opt/metasploit/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.15.0/ext/gem_make.out`?

Comment: @Dboy1612 have you solved your problem?